# Receiving JSON in salesforce

Tags: json, salesforce, apex-code

I am trying to receive a JSON string in salesforce by converting a blob in the body of an Http request. However, when I convert the blob to a string there are \ characters that get inserted into the request which prevents me from parsing.

I then tried to take the string and remove all \ characters... that didn't work either.

```
RestRequest req = RestContext.request;
    Blob jsonBlob = req.requestBody;
    String jsonString = jsonBlob.toString();
    return jsonString;
```

The original string (the one that is received as a blob) looks like this:

```
{"putTimeCard":{"timecard":{"timeCardID": "","employeeID": ""}}
```

And after converting to a salesforce string and assigned to the jsonString is altered to:

```
{\"putTimeCard\":{\"timecard\":{\"timeCardID\": \"\",\"employeeID\": \"\"}}
```

Has anyone found a solution for this?
Thanks

Comment: I think that calling JSON.deserialize will unencode your jsonString.

Comment: will that deserialize it into an object?

Comment: yes, you need to pass the class, see the official doc: http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_methods_system_json.htm

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The JSON Deserializer can parse the string with the escape characters. You can either deserialize into an object like so:

```
String jsonString = '{\"putTimeCard\":{\"timecard\":{\"timeCardID\": \"\",\"employeeID\": \"\"}}}'
Timecard t = (Timecard) JSON.deserialize(jsonString, Type.forName('Timecard'));
```

or if you just want a map of objects you can do the following:

```
String jsonString = '{\"putTimeCard\":{\"timecard\":{\"timeCardID\": \"\",\"employeeID\": \"\"}}}'
Map<String, Object> m = (Map<String, Object>) JSON.deserializeUntyped(jsonString);
```

Comment: I've tried this method, but I always get "message": "System.NullPointerException: Attempt to de-reference a null object\n\n(System Code)\nClass.mobile_Timecard.putTimecard: line 75, column 1",
    "errorCode": "APEX_ERROR" Where line 75 is the line that I attempt to deserialize... Does the custom object have to mirror perfectly?

Comment: Can you post the relevant code? That doesn't sound like an error with the JSON parser necessarily.

I've tested the second method in anonymous apex and it definitely works.

Comment: Thanks for the code, it helped me deserialize the JSON without creating an object for the data. Following to that, if you want the data value, you do 

`Map<String,Object> putTimeCard= (Map<String,Object>)m.get('putTimeCard');`
`Map<String,Object> timecard= (Map<String,Object>)m.get('timecard');`
`String timeCardID = (String)timecard.get('timeCardID');`